Astro 5.0.2 with vitest: getViteConfig and renderToSting of container fail
I just upgraded my Astro site to 5.0.2, but there seem to be breaking changes As per the docs, I use the following vitest config (root of project):
/// <reference types="vitest/config" />
import { getViteConfig } from 'astro/config';

export default getViteConfig({
    test: { <-- Syntax highlighting complains here that this does not exist.
      include: ['./tests/*.{test,spec}.?(c|m)[jt]s?(x)'],
      reporters: [
        'default',
        ['junit', { suiteName: 'UI tests' }]
      ],
    }
  });

Then, I have a mock component:
---
const { title, date } = Astro.props;
---
<div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{date}</p>
</div>

On which I try to run the following test:
import { experimental_AstroContainer as AstroContainer } from 'astro/container';
import { expect, test } from 'vitest';
import Card from '../src/components/Card.astro';

test('Card with slots', async () => {
  const container = await AstroContainer.create();
  const result = await container.renderToString(Card, {
    props: {title: "Title", date: "20 Aug 2024"}
  });

  //expect(result).toContain('This is a card');
  //expect(result).toContain('Card content');
});

Now, if I run with the above configuration, I get:
Vitest caught 2 unhandled errors during the test run.
This might cause false positive tests. Resolve unhandled errors to make sure your tests are not affected.

I can run with the normal vitest defineConfig, but then I get:
Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.

Althought I do not see any error. I know that for getViteConfig, there has been an issue, but this is long closed.
Versions:
Astro: 5.0.2
Vitest: "^2.1.8"
Any Ideas?

Did you try it without the vitest config ? For me it was working without it, I believe it's only necessary if you need to override certain behaviours

The test does not exist error usually occurs when multiple versions of Vite are used, and Vitest has reverted its support for Vite 6 in v2.1.7. So I think that's why you encountered errors (incompatibility between Vite 5 and 6). See: https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/12384#issuecomment-2518454808

@Armand, Thanks for the hint. But that means We'll all have to wait until vitest is up to speed with vite 6? Or use a workaround, which I am very reluctant to do.

@thomi According to an opened issue in Vitest repo, Vite 6 will only be supported with Vitest 3 expected in January... So either you'll wait or you can try the beta version of Vitest 3 or you use an override in the meantime. The override works well for me.
